# Combination problem on number of possible blankets.

Tags: combinatorics

How many blankets can be made if a blanket consists of 3 horizontal stripes, each has a texture and color. If there are 5 colors and can't be repeated and 3 textures which can be repeated: How many sheets can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume we can distinguish between the top and bottom stripes

You have 5 possible colours for the bottom stripe, 4 colours for the central stripe and 3 colours for the top stripe. In total $5 \times 4 \times 3=60$ possible ways to colour the stripes.
Now each stripes can have 3 possible textures, therefore you can have 3 choices of texture for the bottom stripe, 3 choices for the central stripe and 3 choices for the top stripe (in total, $3^3$ choices).

Multiplying all together, you get $60 \times 3^3=1620$ blankets.

If you cannot distinguish between the top and bottom stripe, divide the above by...

Comment: Yes, we cannnot distinguish between top and bottom, They are blankets, they can move. What should we do now?

Comment: @user4140 well, you have to divide 1620 by… (Hint: permute top and bottom stripes).

Answer (score 1):

First choose the colours. There are 5 choices for the first colour, 4 for the next, and 3 for the last. So there are $5*4*3=60$ possible choices for colour. Each may have any of the possible 3 textures, so the answer is $60*3^{3}=1620$ possible sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  The three colors for the stripes can be chosen without being repeated by

${5\choose1}*{4\choose1}*{3\choose1}$

The textures for the three stripes can be chosen with repetition by $3^3$

Hence the total number of ways = ${5\choose1}*{4\choose1}*{3\choose1}*3^{3}$

Thanks

Satish